# Windows 10 latest update (19045.3324) is Resetting Click once Applications

Tags: .net, windows-10

I'm a big fan of Windows. However, since August 9th, we've observed that our clients are facing problems with the latest Windows 10 update (19045.3324). This update seems to remove our "click once application," leaving behind only an icon that lacks its original image. When users click on this icon, they're prompted to reinstall the app. What's more troubling is that if a user shuts down their PC and restarts it the next day, the issue recurs. It's been a consistent challenge for both our clients and the tech support team. We're hopeful that Microsoft will address this soon. If anyone else is experiencing this problem, please share your insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, Microsoft is aware of it here is the link :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-22h2#apps-deployed-via-clickonce-might-prompt-for-installation-when-opened